# AES ECB encrypt/decrypt only decrypts the first 16 bytes

Tags: c, openssl, aes

I had function that decode AES 256 string but it return only 16 char

```
bool decrypt_block(unsigned char* cipherText, unsigned char* plainText, unsigned char* key)
{
    AES_KEY decKey;
    if (AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 256, &decKey) < 0)
        return false;
    AES_decrypt(cipherText, plainText, &decKey);
    return true;
}
```

---

```
decrypt_block( encoded, resultText, ( unsigned char *) "57f4dad48e7a4f7cd171c654226feb5a");
```

Any idea

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you are confusing key length and block size.

AES can be used with 3 different **key lengths**: 128-bits, 192-bits & 256-bits.

AES always uses a **block size** of 128 bits (16 bytes).  For messages that are more than 16 bytes long, you need to decrypt (or encrypt) 16 bytes at a time and expect to get 16 bytes of output each time.  (You will also need to decide which mode to use - e.g. CBC, CTR, ECB, etc..  If you're decrypting text provided by somebody else then that decision has already been taken for you.  If making the decision for yourself, bear in mind that ECB is almost never the right choice.)  If the message isn't a multiple of 16 bytes long, you'll need to [pad it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) so that it is.  PKCS #7 padding is the most common.

See the [Wikipedia article on AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

AES is a block cipher. It encrypts and decrypts a block of 128 bits (16 bytes).
AES_decrypt and AES_encrypt acts on a single block at a time. So, you will get only first 16 bytes. You have to manually decrypt or encrypt other blocks.

If you know the mode (like CBC, ECB etc.), you can call functions such AES_decrypt_cbc etc.

You need to modify the code as follows (I am giving just an example):

```
 int len = strlen(ciphertext); //or get cipher text length by any mean.
 int i;
 for(i=0; i<=len; i+=16)
    AES_decrypt(cipherText+i, plainText+i, &decKey);
```

If you are sure about mode, call cbc/ecb/cfb/ofb mode functions.

In case of any doubt, please let me know.

Comment: error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'const char *'

Comment: OK its working:  ----  strlen( ( const char *) cipherText);   ---

Comment: yep but only working with short string, is is bigger return error

Comment: Check the error. One thing I forgot to mention that for AES_decrypt, the encrypted message must be of 16 bytes exactly. If your large string is not in the multiple of 16 bytes, you need to pad it. In your case, if encrypted string is not in multiple of 16 bytes, it means there is some error.

Comment: Use ERR_get_error or ERR_print_errors_fp to print the error and source of error on file.

Comment: What do you mean by broken data?

Comment: This broken data: (unsigned char*)encod.c_str()

Comment: Is there any '\0' in encod?

Comment: Problem is with strlen so i just add another param to function with length

Comment: Try strlen ( char *) its impossible because when string has end byte will be cut in this possitoon. So i add another param in function with strlen