# AES_decrypt not working

Tags: openssl, aes

I am trying below code but the output is not as expected.

```
uint8_t ss_key[32];
uint8_t enc_out[80];
AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
uint8_t data[32]="YOGENDRASINGHHGNISARDNEGOY12345";
uint8_t data_out[32];

memset(data_out,0,sizeof(data_out));
if (!RAND_bytes(ss_key, sizeof(ss_key))) {
    cout<<"error random value"<<endl;
}

AES_set_encrypt_key(ss_key, 128, &enc_key);
AES_set_decrypt_key(ss_key, 128, &dec_key);
AES_encrypt(data, enc_out, &enc_key);
AES_decrypt(enc_out, data_out, &dec_key);

cout<<data<<endl;
cout<<"reverse"<<endl;

for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
    cout<<data_out[i];
}
```

**output:**

```
YOGENDRASINGHHGNISARDNEGOY12345

reverse

YOGENDRASINGHHGN
```

Comment: I think is your duplicate: [AES_encrypt/AES_decrypt only returns part of a message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15375854/608639).

Answer (score 1):

> YOGENDRASINGHHGNISARDNEGOY12345
>
> reverse
>
> YOGENDRASINGHHGN

`AES_encrypt` only operates on a 16-byte block. Its up to you to add padding to the final block and handle multiple blocks. That's why `YOGENDRASINGHHGN` (block 1) is encrypted and decrypted, but `ISARDNEGOY12345` (block 2) is not.

Its also up to you to do thing like XOR in an vector for each block of of plain text or encrypted text. That is, you are responsible for adding the "mode of operation".

Your clue to the problem is, there's no length parameter accompanying the `in` and `out` pointers:

```
$ grep -IR AES_encrypt | grep void
crypto/aes/aes_core.c:void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
crypto/aes/aes_x86core.c:void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
...
```

And then, from [`crypto/aes/aes_core.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/aes/aes_core.c):

```
/*
 * Encrypt a single block
 * in and out can overlap
 */
void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out, const AES_KEY *key) {
    ...
}
```

You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. It has some additional downsides. It's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like Intel AES-NI or ARMv8a with Crypto. On some platforms you also have to manage endianness.

You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.